# Unable to display our details in profile page?

Tags: django

I've created a project using Django. Login and Registration are working fine but I'm unable to display model `User` data on the profile page, I've tried so many ways but the information is not displaying. Only admin User related data is displaying.

views.py

```
 def maas(request,maas_username_slug):
   context_dict = {}

   try:
      maas = Maas.objects.get(slug=maas_username_slug)
      context_dict['maas_username'] = maas.username
      context_dict['maas_username_slug'] = maas_username_slug
      context_dict['maas_phone'] = maas.phone
      context_dict['maas_firstname'] = maas.firstname
      context_dict['maas_lastname'] = maas.lastname
      context_dict['maas_location'] = maas.location
      context_dict['date_of_birth'] = maas.date_of_birth
      context_dict['comments'] = maas.comments
      context_dict['maas_gender'] = maas.gender
      context_dict['photo'] = maas.photo
      context_dict['maas'] = maas
   except Maas.DoesNotExist:
      pass
   print(context_dict)
   return render(request, 'testapp/profile.html', {'context_dict': context_dict})
```

urls.py

```
url(r'(?P<maas_username_slug>\w+)/$', views.maas, name='profile'),
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Maas(models.Model):

    username=models.CharField(max_length=25)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    phone = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(blank=True)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True)
    comments = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/photos/', null=True, 
    blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True,default="")
```

profile.html

```
{%extends 'testapp/base.html'%}
{%block body_block%}
<h1>Profile page</h1>
<h1>{{ maas_username }} welcome to your profile page</h1>

<li>{{maas_username}}</li>
<li>{{maas_phone}}</li>
<li>{{maas_lastname}}</li>

{%endfor%}
```

Comment: where is template code?

Comment: please check it i've saved .

Comment: When i used Maas.objects.all(). i able to display data on profile but all users data will be displaying from db . i need only current login user details.

Comment: does your print statement show you're picking up a record?

Comment: 'testapp/profile.html' is replaced with 'template_url' right?

Comment: i will suggest that you should try to run your code without `try-except` and check if there is any error.

Comment: with out try-except error showing testapp.models.DoesNotExist: Maas matching query does not exist.

Comment: @manu this clearly says that you don't have any data for the given username.

Comment: iam change code with is login only used Maas.objects.all() all userdata will displaying including login user details also

Comment: @manu what is the slug you are providing to your views? maybe your lookup is not correct, you can try `Maas.objects.get(username=request.user.username)`, if you using the default Auth model.

Comment: slug=maas_username_slug

Comment: @manu try to get the data with `Maas.objects.get(username=request.user.username)`

Comment: tryed not printing anyting profile.html

Comment: @manu if you didn't get any error with `Maas.objects.get(username=request.user.username)` it means the lookup is correct but you dont have any data. You need to add some data for the user.

Comment: i checked login user have the data using print(maas) related details also displaying on console but not displaying in template .,and i am using other cod option   Maas.objects.all() then it will displaying current userdetails and all database user details also.

Answer (score 0):

rename `context_dict` to `context` and in return `render(request, 'testapp/profile.html', context)`

and one thing if your `try block fail` than `context will be None` so it's `print nothing`

**update**

```
def maas(request,maas_username_slug):
   context_dict = {}

   try:
      maas = Maas.objects.get(slug=maas_username_slug)
      context_dict['maas_username'] = maas.username
      context_dict['maas_username_slug'] = maas_username_slug
      context_dict['maas_phone'] = maas.phone
      context_dict['maas_firstname'] = maas.firstname
      context_dict['maas_lastname'] = maas.lastname
      context_dict['maas_location'] = maas.location
      context_dict['date_of_birth'] = maas.date_of_birth
      context_dict['comments'] = maas.comments
      context_dict['maas_gender'] = maas.gender
      context_dict['photo'] = maas.photo
      context_dict['maas'] = maas
   except Maas.DoesNotExist as ex:
      # if your code get exception than context_dict will be none.
      # that's why in html their is nothing to print.
      # I said it above 
      context_dict['error'] = ex
   print(context_dict)
   return render(request, 'testapp/profile.html', context=context_dict)
```

in `html`

```
<h1>Profile page</h1>
<h1>{{ error }} </h1> <!-- here if error occured than error message will pring -->
<h1>{{ maas_username }} welcome to your profile page</h1>

<li>{{maas_username}}</li>
<li>{{maas_phone}}</li>
<li>{{maas_lastname}}</li>
```

Comment: i uesd return render(request, 'testapp/profile.html', context=context_dict) but not printing annthing

Answer (score 0):

It's because the context on your template is not the same as your expectation. In this case, on your template you can access these values like this:

```
{%extends 'testapp/base.html'%}
{%block body_block%}
<h1>Profile page</h1>
<h1>{{ context_dict.maas_username }} welcome to your profile page</h1>

<li>{{ context_dict.maas_username}}</li>
<li>{{ context_dict.maas_phone}}</li>
<li>{{ context_dict.maas_lastname}}</li>

{%endfor%}
```

I recommend you to set `context_dict` as `context` param for render function instead of create new dictionary for that or you just need to pass context_dict as a second param on the render function's params. Like so:

```
return render(request, 'testapp/profile.html', context=context_dict)
```

or:

```
return render(request, 'testapp/profile.html', context_dict)
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: `print(context_dict)` did you see this variable printed on the console? I just worry that maybe the block doesn't exists in the base template so I think you can move it out side of the block to test it first then @manu

Comment: How about `maas_username_slug`? is it contain any value? If yes then the issue is there is no Mass object in the database which match your query.

Comment: no maas_username_slug not contain any value just iu mentioned in views only

Comment: wow.. could you give me the url which you use to access to that view? I wonder how you can access to that view without `maas_username_slug`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
<h1>{{ maas_username }} welcome to your profile page</h1>

<li>{{maas_username}}</li>
<li>{{maas_phone}}</li>
<li>{{maas_lastname}}</li>
```

You need to change these to :

```
<h1>{{ context_dict.maas_username }} welcome to your profile page</h1>

<li>{{context_dict.maas_username}}</li>
<li>{{context_dict.maas_phone}}</li>
<li>{{context_dict.maas_lastname}}</li>
```

The reason why is you are passing a dictionary (A single object), and therefore you need to attempt to retrieve it's value of keys

Comment: i changed but not displaying

Comment: Have you checked whether it is the same template which is being rendered.

Comment: Just add a print statement regarding `context_dict` before executing the HTTPResponse in the view and show me the output

Comment: added not displaing any data on console in templates also not printing anything.

Comment: Try to print `maas` and `mass_username_slug`

Comment: using print(maas)  data displaying on console.not displaying for maas_username_slug

Comment: Can you show me the output of both cases in console.

Comment: Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
{'maas_username': 'man', 'maas_phone': 9490566775, 'maas_firstname': 'Arepalli', 'maas_lastname': 'leelamanush',
cation': 'Punai', 'date_of_birth': datetime.date(1991, 4, 22), 'comments': '', 'maas_gender': 'Arepalli l', 'phot
geFieldFile: media/photos/c.jpg>, 'maas': <Maas: man>}
[04/Sep/2019 13:00:29] "GET /profile/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2340
Performing system checks...

Comment: System check identified no issues (0 silenced).

You have 4 unapplied migration(s). Your project may not work properly until you apply the migrations for app(s):

Run 'python manage.py migrate' to apply them.
September 04, 2019 - 13:01:25
Django version 1.11, using settings 'maaproject.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
Performing system checks...

Comment: Can you use show me the output of `context_dict` whether it is null or something.

Comment: System check identified no issues (0 silenced).

You have 4 unapplied migration(s). Your project may not work properly until you apply the migrations for app(s):

Run 'python manage.py migrate' to apply them.
September 04, 2019 - 13:32:46
Django version 1.11, using settings 'maaproject.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.

Comment: @manu this is not the output of the context. Post the data of the context. And also run `python manage.py migrate`.

Comment: error showing at the time of migrate django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: testapp_maas.user_id

Answer (score 0):

if u named your dict name is "context"
then it may be

```
{% for context in context %}
<h1>{{ context.maas_username }} welcome to your profile page</h1>
<li>{{ context.maas_username}}</li>
<li>{{ context.maas_phone}}</li>
<li>{{ context.maas_lastname}}</li>
{% endfor %}
```